# How to make ip route settings persistent in CentOS?

Tags: centos, init.d, iproute2

I need to route the outgoing traffic via a virtual ip address. I can do this using the 'ip' tool from the iproute-package.

Using `ip route` I can see which address is used as the source and I can change it using `ip route change`, but this is temporary and I loose this change after restarting the network service or the machine.

How can I do this using config files so that it's persistent? For example I was trying several options in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0:0` but no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general you can easily add anything you want to run at boot time to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`. So just add whatever `ip route` commands you want there. Simple and no messing around.

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Installation_Guide-en-US/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html

> The /etc/rc.d/rc.local script is executed by the init command at boot
>   time or when changing runlevels. Adding commands to the bottom of this
>   script is an easy way to perform necessary tasks like starting special
>   services or initialize devices without writing complex initialization
>   scripts in the /etc/rc.d/init.d/ directory and creating symbolic
>   links.

Or

You can go the more complex way and create a systemd service. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sect-Managing_Services_with_systemd-Unit_Files.html

That way you can set it up to restart with the networking services.

Or

Perhaps you can make use of the custom network scripts in CentOS

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-NetworkManager_and_the_Network_Scripts.html

Custom Commands and the Network Scripts

> Custom commands in the scripts /sbin/ifup-local, ifdown-pre-local, and
>   ifdown-local are only executed when those devices are controlled by
>   the /etc/init.d/network service. If you modified the initscripts
>   themselves (for example, /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth) then
>   those changes would be overwritten by an initscripts package update.
>   Therefore it is recommend that you avoid modifying the initscripts
>   directly and make use of the /sbin/if*local scripts, so that your
>   custom changes will survive package updates. The initscripts just
>   check for the presence of the relevant /sbin/if*local and run them if
>   they exist. The initscripts do not place anything in the
>   /sbin/if*local scripts, nor does the initscripts RPM (or any package)
>   own or modify those files.

Comment: Yes but if the network service is restarted the route config loose

Comment: @user3849013 I updated my answer with more options for you

Answer (score 1):

[You had to edit the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0:0` file](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Configuring_Static_Routes_in_ifcfg_files.html#sec-networkscripts-static-routes-ip-command), adding an entry with the following syntax: `<SUBNET>/<PREFIX_LENGTH> via <GATEWAY> dev <INTERFACE>`

For example: `10.10.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0:0`

Comment: Assuming init.d and networking service, you don't edit the scripts, you edit the config files that the scripts load.  e.g., if you call `ifup etho` or `ifdown eth0`, it refers to the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`.  If you're using systemd and/or NetworkManager service, best bet is to use NetworkManager to set it up.  Better to use the network-scripts config files, as this example demonstrates, the routes will be part of the network config and will automatically reload.